# SSIS Export to Excel using Script Task

Tags: c#, excel, ssis

I'm trying to use a Script Task to export data to Excel because some of the reports I generate simply have too many columns to keep using a template file.

The most annoying part about using a template is: if something as simple as a column header changes, the metadata gets screwed forcing me to recreate my DataFlow.  Because I use an OLE DB source, I need to use a Data Transformation task to convert between unicode and non-unicode character sets, then remap my Excel Destination to the "Copy of field x" in order for the Excel document to create properly.
This takes far too long and I need a new approach.

I have the following method in a script task using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel:

```
private void ExportToExcel(DataTable dataTable, string excelFilePath = null)
    {

        Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Worksheet workSheet = null;

        try
        {
            if (dataTable == null || dataTable.Columns.Count == 0)
                throw new System.Exception("Null or empty input table!" + Environment.NewLine);

            excelApp.Workbooks.Add();

            workSheet = excelApp.ActiveSheet;

            for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                workSheet.Cells[1, (i + 1)] = dataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName;
            }

            foreach (DataTable dt in dataSet.Tables)
            {

                // Copy the DataTable to an object array
                object[,] rawData = new object[dt.Rows.Count + 1, dt.Columns.Count];

                // Copy the column names to the first row of the object array
                for (int col = 0; col < dt.Columns.Count; col++)
                {
                    rawData[0, col] = dt.Columns[col].ColumnName;
                }

                // Copy the values to the object array
                for (int col = 0; col < dt.Columns.Count; col++)
                {
                    for (int row = 0; row < dt.Rows.Count; row++)
                    {
                        rawData[row + 1, col] = dt.Rows[row].ItemArray[col];
                    }
                }

                // Calculate the final column letter
                string finalColLetter = string.Empty;
                string colCharset = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
                int colCharsetLen = colCharset.Length;

                if (dt.Columns.Count > colCharsetLen)
                {
                    finalColLetter = colCharset.Substring((dt.Columns.Count - 1) / colCharsetLen - 1, 1);
                }

                finalColLetter += colCharset.Substring((dt.Columns.Count - 1) % colCharsetLen, 1);

                workSheet.Name = dt.TableName;

                // Fast data export to Excel
                string excelRange = string.Format("A1:{0}{1}", finalColLetter, dt.Rows.Count + 1);


                //The code crashes here (ONLY in SSIS):
                workSheet.get_Range(excelRange, Type.Missing).Value2 = rawData;

                // Mark the first row as BOLD
                ((Excel.Range)workSheet.Rows[1, Type.Missing]).Font.Bold = true;
            }

            List<int> lstColumnsToSum = new List<int>() { 9 };
            Dictionary<int, string> dictColSumName = new Dictionary<int, string>() { { 9, "" } };
            Dictionary<int, decimal> dictColumnSummation = new Dictionary<int, decimal>() { { 9, 0 } };

            // rows
            for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= dataTable.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    workSheet.Cells[(i + 2), (j)] = dataTable.Rows[i][j - 1];
                    if (lstColumnsToSum.Exists(x => (x == j)))
                    {
                        decimal val = 0;
                        if (decimal.TryParse(dataTable.Rows[i][j - 1].ToString(), out val))
                        {
                            dictColumnSummation[j] += val;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            //Footer
            int footerRowIdx = 2 + dataTable.Rows.Count;

            foreach (var summablecolumn in dictColSumName)
            {
                workSheet.Cells[footerRowIdx, summablecolumn.Key] = String.Format("{0}", dictColumnSummation[summablecolumn.Key]);
            }

            // check fielpath
            if (excelFilePath != null && excelFilePath != "")
            {
                try
                {
                    if (File.Exists(excelFilePath))
                        File.Delete(excelFilePath);

                    workSheet.Activate();
                    workSheet.Application.ActiveWindow.SplitRow = 1;
                    workSheet.Application.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = true;

                    int row = 1;
                    int column = 1;

                    foreach (var item in dataTable.Columns)
                    {
                        Excel.Range range = workSheet.Cells[row, column] as Excel.Range;
                        range.NumberFormat = "@";
                        range.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
                        range.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightGray);
                        column++;
                    }

                    Excel.Range InternalCalculatedAmount = workSheet.Cells[1, 9] as Excel.Range;
                    InternalCalculatedAmount.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "#0.00";
                    InternalCalculatedAmount.Columns.AutoFit();

                    workSheet.SaveAs(excelFilePath);
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new System.Exception("Excel file could not be saved! Check filepath." + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message);
                }
            }
            else    // no filepath is given
            {
                excelApp.Visible = true;
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            throw new System.Exception("ex.Message + Environment.NewLine, ex.InnerException);
        }
    }
```

The exception thrown is a System.OutOfMemoryException when trying to execute the following piece of code:

```
workSheet.get_Range(excelRange, Type.Missing).Value2 = rawData;
```

My biggest frustration is that this method works 100% in a regular C# application.

The DataTable contains about 435000 rows.  I know it's quite a bit of data but I use this very method, modified of course, to split data across multiple Excel worksheets in one of my other applications, and that DataSet contains about 1.1m rows.  So less than half of my largest DataSet should be a walk-in-the-park...

Any light shed on this matter would be amazing!

Comment: @BIDeveloper: Say WHAT?  I spend half my life maintaining a template file. This script works generically and it requires VERY LITTLE maintenance. It has solved 99% of my Excel export problems in C# apps. It just doesn't work so well in SSIS. This script doesn't care about additions / changes to anything as it exports a DataTable.  Please elaborate your statement?

Comment: I think that the reason why this isn't working in SSIS is that you open the Excel application in the background to communicate your data into the file.